# How to get full coverage of a CLI nodeJS app with istanbul?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, command-line-interface, istanbul

I am using this config :Istanbul/Mocha/Chai/supertest(for http tests)/sinon (for timer tests) but I am having some problem with testing CLI tools

My question is simple: How can I test my cli program and achieve at the same time 100% code coverage with istanbul? No matter what tool you are using, I would like to understand how you are doing it please!

I found this article which was very helpful at the beginning but

- It was written in 2014
- The module **mock-utf8-stream** does not seem standard
- It does not explain clearly the code architecture

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be done in 2 steps:

1. Make sure your test suite is set up to correctly spawn the CLI execution
2. Set up `nyc` (reason for switching from `istanbul` to `nyc` explained below) to go through the script files behind your CLI tool

### Setting up your tests to run spawn subprocesses

I had to set up some CLI tests a few months ago on [Fulky](https://github.com/astorije/fulky) (the project is paused right now but it's temporary) and wrote my test suite as such:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

describe('Executing my CLI tool', function () {
  // If your CLI tool is taking some expected time to start up / tear down, you
  // might want to set this to avoid slowness warnings.
  this.slow(600);

  it('should pass given 2 arguments', () => {
    const result = spawnSync(
      './my-CLI-tool',
      ['argument1', 'argument2'],
      { encoding: 'utf-8' }
    );

    expect(result.status).to.equal(0);
    expect(result.stdout).to.include('Something from the output');
  });
});
```

You can see [an example here](https://github.com/astorije/fulky/blob/master/test/runners/mocha.test.js) but bear in mind that this is a test file **run with Mocha**, that **runs Mocha in a spawned process**.
A bit Inception for your need here so it might be confusing, but it's testing a Mocha plugin hence the added brain game. That should apply to your use case though if you forget about that complexity.

### Setting up coverage

You will then want to install [`nyc`](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) with `npm i nyc --save-dev`, nowadays' CLI tool for Istanbul, because as opposed to the previous CLI (`istanbul` itself), it allows coverage for applications that spawn subprocesses.
Good thing is it's still the same tool, the same team, etc. behind `nyc`, so the switch is really trivial (for example, see [this transition](https://github.com/thelounge/lounge/pull/850)).

In your `package.json`, then add to your `scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
  "coverage": "nyc mocha"
}
```

You will then get a report with `npm run coverage` (you will probably have to set the `reporter` option in `.nycrc`) that goes through your CLI scripts as well.

I haven't set up this coverage part with the project mentioned above, but I have just applied these steps locally and it works as expected so I invite you to try it out on your end.